# how can i kill all established connections before running iptables bash scrip

Tags: command-line, scripts, iptables, firewall, connection

there is established connection from before running iptables bash script, and even this connection is blocked by iptables, but it keeps running  because it is in established status, which according to iptables every established connection is allowed ...
Is there anyway to kill all established connections without have to disconnect the firewall from the internet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flush the entire connection tacking table with this command:

```
sudo conntrack --flush
```

You will need the conntrack package:

```
sudo apt install conntrack
```